# How to resize a screenshot so together with its explanation it fits one document page

Tags: microsoft-word, documents, documentation, writing

I am writing instructions for tablet/smartphone users. Generally I have one screenshot and some explaining text on one document page (currently a Word document). Is it **automatically** possible in Word to resize a screenshot so it fits on the remaining space of a page?

Answer (score 1):

When you insert a picture into Word and have the image selected, a contextual Picture Format tab opens on Word’s ribbon.

[image]

As you can see in the above clip, Word includes the ability to Crop or Resize images once they are in the document.

A third party Word add-in alternative that includes a few more features that you can include as you insert the picture is one I wrote. It’s called **AuthorTec Insert**. You can do a web search on the product name to get more information.

[image]